# Comparing two text files in Windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have two text boxes where a user enters their paths to the text files to compare. When they enter the path I am doing the following to get the whole content of each file by reading line by line and finally keeping them in strings.

So far it's working but I need to take first 10 characters from file2 and see if those 10 characters exists in file1. If they exist then increase a counter otherwise go to next 10 characters from file2 and compare them in file1. It should continue until end of file2.

```
private void btnCompare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FilePath1 = txtFile1.Text;
    string FilePath2 = txtFile2.Text;
    string CompleteStringToCompare = "";
    string CompleteStringToCompareWith = "";
    int counter = 0;

    //Read First file
    if (!File.Exists(FilePath1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} does not exist.", FilePath1);
        return;
    }
    using (StreamReader sr1 = File.OpenText(FilePath1))
    {
        string input1;
        while ((input1 = sr1.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            CompleteStringToCompare += input1;
        }
    }

    //Read Second file
    if (!File.Exists(FilePath2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} does not exist.", FilePath2);
        return;
    }
    using (StreamReader sr2 = File.OpenText(FilePath2))
    {
        string input2;
        while ((input2 = sr2.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            CompleteStringToCompareWith += input2; 
        }
        
    }
}
```

How do I loop through string `CompleteStringToCompareWith` for each 10 characters and see if those exact 10 characters exists in string `CompleteStringToCompare` until you reach end of string `CompleteStringToCompareWith`?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at trying it yourself? I don't see any code in the block you posted that even comes close to doing that.

Comment: Do not reinvent the whee, Why not use a third party library like [DiffPlex](http://diffplex.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I need to show how many 10 characters are matched and how much percentage is matched and text files are with continuous characters not separated in words

Comment: Move your edit into an answer and mark it as such, otherwise this question will be undead forever...

Comment: @Tiger thank you, and it is also acceptable to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I did write the rest of the code what I needed. Here it is:

```
int length = int.Parse(txtNumberOfChar.Text);  //Which is 10 in my case
int j = 1;
string temp = "";
if (CompleteStringToCompareWith != "")
{
    int totalSubStrings = CompleteStringToCompareWith.Length / length;
    for (int i = 1; i <= totalSubStrings; i++)
    {
        if (i == totalSubStrings)
            temp = CompleteStringToCompareWith.Substring(j, CompleteStringToCompareWith.Length - j);
        else
            temp = CompleteStringToCompareWith.Substring(j, length);

        if (CompleteStringToCompare.Contains(temp))
            counter++;
        j = j + length;
    }

    lblMessage.Text = "Total Matches "+ counter;
}
```